# Ruby on Rails - Errno::EACCES (Mac 10.9.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, rvm

I installed Ruby (v. 2.1.2) and Rails (v. 4.1.4). When i try to start server (using the command rails s) I get an error:

```
`Could not find columnize-0.8.9 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.`
```

when i run the `bundle install`, i get:

```
`...Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/BBB/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/columnize-0.8.9/.gitignore 
An error occurred while installing columnize (0.8.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that gem install columnize -v '0.8.9' succeeds before bundling.`
```

and then i try `gem install columnize -v '0.8.9'`
i get permission denied~

```
`ERROR:While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/BBB/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/columnize-0.8.9/.gitignore`
```

does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try `rvmsudo gem install columnize -v '0.8.9'`?

Comment: Thx a lot! but, after this error fixed, another "permission denied"question emerge. I also try your suggestion `rvmsudo ...`, it also fixed it!

can i ask that why so many "permission denied" happened?

Answer (score 0):

The /Users/bor-shyangsheu/.rvm/ is the directory that is in user home and it is a local path for the user (that is /Users/bor-shyangsheu/) and it should really be owned by 'bor-shyangsheu' user.

Therefore, installing stuff with sudo does not make any sense.

And, I guess the setup or the gem installation had been wrong before ( you might accidentally used `sudo gem install` before etc.) which have led you to the permission problem later on (including this one)

I think what you should do now is.

1. Check what group that the user 'bor-shyangsheu' belongs to.

   `id bor-shyangsheu`
   or just type `id` if you're currently logged in as 'bor-shyangsheu'
2. Change all of the directorys and files owner to be owned by `bor-shyangsheu` and his group by

   `sudo chown -Rf bor-shyangsheu:<group name> /Users/bor-shyangsheu/.rvm/*`

   For instance, if the group name is 'staff', run this command

   `sudo chown -Rf bor-shyangsheu:staff /Users/bor-shyangsheu/.rvm/*`
3. Always use `gem install <gem name>` later.

Hope this clarifies thing a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You may try deleting the "Gemfile.lock". You can learn more at [Bundler.io](http://bundler.io/v1.3/rationale.html).

> After developing your application for a while, check in the application together with the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock snapshot. Now, your repository has a record of the exact versions of all of the gems that you used the last time you know for sure that the application worked. Keep in mind that while your Gemfile lists only three gems (with varying degrees of version strictness), your application depends on dozens of gems, once you take into consideration all of the implicit requirements of the gems you depend on.
>
> This is important: the Gemfile.lock makes your application a single package of both your own code and the third-party code it ran the last time you know for sure that everything worked. Specifying exact versions of the third-party code you depend on in your Gemfile would not provide the same guarantee, because gems usually declare a range of versions for their dependencies.